# Interrupted android app when it minimize and open another app

Tags: android

I am working on a GPS app that working fine when it start, but when I minimize it and open some other app then it not give latitude and longitude continusly and when I close other app and run this single app then it give accurate result. anybody have any idea about it then please help me..

Comment: post your code what have you done

Answer (score 0):

you should use `service` to run in background. when you open other app than it gps app will be gone in pause method. and after that stop method. and when you reopen it it will call restart method.

so as i think you have to use service for gps lat and lng. service will continuously running in background.

Answer (score 0):

Well! It's happening just because of you activity in background mode. When you minimize your application that means Activity stop() method called and then stoped your Activity.

## Solution

For this case you have to use the service like this example

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener{

  //public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;

    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
      //intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,20000, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location,Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }
        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use
        // the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be
            // worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and
        // accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate
                && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally { }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }   

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("***", "Location changed");
        if (isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
            double latI = loc.getLatitude();
            double longI  = loc.getLongitude();
            //Put Data into shared prefrence
             SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(ApplicationCardinality.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);;
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
             editor.putString("gpsLatitude", ""+latI);
             editor.putString("gpsLongitude", ""+longI);
             editor.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { } 

}
```

Comment: no! not like this when, I test in Genymotion it's working well.. but I test in android mobile then... start and minimize now if no any app are open like Facebook and chrome.. then there result are interrupted ...